# How to delete a substring after a certain word?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a long String and want to delete the part of the String that comes after a word and I'm looking for the gsub! command that does that. I would appreciate it if you could provide it.

For reference:
I know that the command to delete the part of the String (the String is called contents) that comes before the word "body" is:

```
 contents.gsub!(/.*?(?=body)/im, "")
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: Sorry I included an html tag in my question as "the word" and it wouldn't display correctly so my question didn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
"this has a word in it".gsub! /(word).*/, $1
```

Will change the string to `"this has a word"`

The "word" in brackets is the first argument returned by the regex, and `$1` returns that argument.

[See the Ruby docs for `gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Answer (score 0):

Going by your regex, that requires the `/` in body to be escaped, I'm assuming you mean every after

```
contents = "Stuff before </body> stuff after"
contents.gsub(/(?<=\/body>).+/, "")
=> "Stuff before </body>"
```